# Symfony2/3: Is flushing a single entity/object possible? If not, how can I access objects persisted but not flushed after a foreach loop?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I know that in Doctrine (as a general rule) it is better to flush() after persisting all the entities/objects to the database, but in the following case I think it could be useful to do the opposite.
Example:

Imagine that you are cycling through a list of sport results like this one:

```
playerA_unique_tag (string), playerB_unique_tag (string), result
```

In the database, `playerA` and `playerB` are FOREIGN KEYS (that point to a `User` entity). So, the database structure would be similar to this one:

```
Match record
id, playerA_fk, playerB_fk, result

User records
id, playerA_unique_tag, (etc... many other fields)
id, playerB_unique_tag, (etc... many other fields)
```

Example of a script

```
$sportResultsArray = array();
foreach($sportResultsArray as $sportResult){
    $playerA_tag = $sportResult["$playerA_unique_tag"];
    $db_playerA = db->getRepository("App:User")->findOneByTag($playerA);
    if(!$db_playerA){
        $db_playerA = new User();
        $db_playerA ->setPlayer_unique_tag($playerA_tag);
        $em->persist($db_playerA );
    }

    $match = new Match();
    $match ->setplayerA($db_playerA );
    /*Same thing would be done for playerB*/
    $em->persist($match );
}
```

Problem:
Of course playerA will play MULTIPLE matches, and each time I have to somehow retrieve the corresponding `User` object and pass it to the new `Match` object.
But how can I do that if I haven't flushed playerA `User` object yet.

The only two alternatives I can think of are:
1- Flushing the `User` entity (and ONLY the `User` entity) after it is created
2- Create a temporary array of objects like this:
`array('playerA_unique_tag' => playerA_Object, etc.)`

Problem with option_1:
I have tried `$em->flush($db_playerA);` but every entity that was persisted to the Entity Manager also gets flushed (contrary to what written here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#338-359). Basically, the result is the same as `$em->flush();`

Problem with option_2:
Isn't it a bad and inefficient workaround?

Comment: *But how can I do that if I haven't flushed playerA User object yet.* Why not? Are you sure you need to flush players to get them to the match `$match ->setplayerA($db_playerA );` ?

Comment: Please be careful... that works of course if $db_playerA was just created (= if I am parsing his FIRST match) BUT if this is the 2nd, 3rd (Nth) match of playerA how can I retrieve the $db_playerA object that I created earlier? I CAN'T create every time a completely new user entity if the player is the same

Comment: Memoize it. Hitting database on each iteration is not the most efficient approach anyway. In fact, I would fetch all players in a single `IN($tags)` call.

Comment: But '$tags' should be an array of objects, right? Sorry if I didn't get it right. It's just that I need to retrieve an object and not just a string.

Comment: Fair enough. It really looks like XY problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to work with in-memory registry of players as following:

```
// init registry
$players = [];
foreach ($sportResultsArray as $sportResult) {
    $players[$sportResult["$playerA_unique_tag"]] = null;
    $players[$sportResult["$playerB_unique_tag"]] = null;
}

// fetch all at once
$existing = $db->getRepository("App:User")->findBy(['tag' => array_keys($players)]);

// fill up the registry
foreach ($existing as $player) {
    $players[$player->getTag()] = $player;
}

// match them up
foreach ($sportResultsArray as $sportResult) {
    $playerA_tag = $sportResult["$playerA_unique_tag"];

    if ($players[$playerA_tag] === null) {
        $players[$playerA_tag] = new User();
        $players[$playerA_tag]->setPlayer_unique_tag($playerA_tag);
        $em->persist($players[$playerA_tag]);
    }

    $match = new Match();
    $match->setplayerA($players[$playerA_tag]);
    /*Same thing would be done for playerB*/
    $em->persist($match);
}

// finally 
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Great!! This is a cleaner implementation of option 2. The key is creating an array of User entities index by player_tag. Well done, it wasn't easy but you were able to solve the problem. I didn't know about the possibility of using ->findBy(['tag' => array_keys($players)]);